# Rails scope with associations

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

So currently I have this scope:

```
  scope :ending_documents, -> { where('document1_valid_to <= ? OR document2_valid_to <= ? OR document3_valid_to <= ? OR document_4_valid_to <= ? ', Time.zone.now.end_of_day + 30.days, Time.zone.now.end_of_day + 30.days, Time.zone.now.end_of_day + 30.days, Time.zone.now.end_of_day + 30.days ) }
```

I'm using this scope to find users who have at least 1 document that ends in 30 days or has ended. But I need to find another document through associations.

```
class User 
  has_many :user_cards

class UsersCard
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :card

class Card
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :user_cards
```

[These are the example tables.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gP4Dy.png)

How can I also add ending cards assigned to the user in same scope? I red about joins but how can I do it when the association goes through like that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use `has_many :through` association

```
class User 
  has_many :user_cards, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :cards, through: :user_cards

  scope :ending_documents, -> { joins(user_cards: :cards).where('users.document1_valid_to <= ? OR users.document2_valid_to <= ? OR users.document3_valid_to <= ? OR users.document_4_valid_to <= ? OR cards.valid_to <= ?', Time.zone.now.end_of_day + 30.days, Time.zone.now.end_of_day + 30.days, Time.zone.now.end_of_day + 30.days, Time.zone.now.end_of_day + 30.days, Time.zone.now.end_of_day + 30.days) }
end
```